# Is it possible to implement Growth Mixture Models/Latent Class Mixed Models in Python? If so, how? R has packages such as lcmm and flexmix for this

Tags: r, python, finite-mixture-model, latent-class, growth-mixture-model

R has lots of support for Finite Mixture Models, as well as specialized packages for more specific Mixture Models for approaches such as Latent Class Mixed Models (lcmm package) and Growth Mixture Models (flexmix package)-- which I believe are effectively the same modeling approach.

https://osf.io/preprints/psyarxiv/m58wx/

I am aware of packages in Python such as PyMix, scikit-mixture, and MixtComp, but I do not believe they have support for Growth Mixture Models/Latent Class Mixed Models. If they can be implemented using these Python packages, could someone help direct me to where in the documentation it describes Growth Mixture Models with these packages? If there is a different library/package for Growth Mixture Models in Python, could someone direct me to where that is and/or how to implement?

Comment: This seems like a software request rather than a question about statistics, but I would suggest using probabilistic programming tools where you can build almost whatever you like.